# Using Nodejs on OS X Server

Tags: macos, node.js, osx-server

## The Problem

I have a mac mini that I'm using as my home server. I also have a domain name, which we'll call example.com. What I would like to know is, how do I enable remote access to a Node.js app (running on a mac mini using OS X Server) that is listening on port 8080?   Ideally, I want blog.example.com to point to this running node app.

## What I've Tried

- Successfully pointed my domain name to my IP address. Therefore, I can access example.com from anywhere
- Changed airport time capsule settings to allow access to port 8080 from within the Server.app
- Started Node.js app, which is listening on port 8080. I can access localhost:8080, but not example.com:8080
- Created an A record for blog.example.com, and verified that DNS has propagated.

So I think my problem might lie in getting OS X server and node.js to work well together, but I could also be missing a few other pieces to the puzzle. Hopefully you guys can help me out or point me to a tutorial that shows how to get this working. Thanks!

Comment: If the app is listening on port 8080, try blog.example.com:8080

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but no luck. Still can't access the server

Comment: I'm not familiar with mac mini but could you please check the code start listening, make sure you are NOT specifying the address. So something like `.listen(8080)` instead of `.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1')`.

Comment: Could you show the node.js code you're running?

Comment: Is this still an ongoing issue? If not, please post your solution for others. Things I would try first are local access, local network access (from within same LAN subnet), then if okay, try the VPN access... I would suggest using the IP address just to validate that you are not having a name resolution issue. If you've tried all of these and still want a solution, please update the post.